# How to stream songs from cloud account on python music player application

Tags: python, audio-streaming, audio-player, cloud-storage, mega-api

I am making a music player application with `Pygame`, initially, I was playing songs that I have downloaded in my local system, now I want to share this app as an executable file with my friends, now the issue is they may not have songs already downloaded on their system nor will the location be the same, hence I thought of uploading the song files on to the cloud, [Mega](https://mega.nz/) in my case, I am a noob and this is the first time I'm exploring something with cloud storage and streaming, Now I want to access the songs stored in my cloud account and play it in my application, basically I need all possible access to every file stored in cloud, since the app does quite a few things like shuffle, next song's title, loop, etc.

My question now is **How to stream the audio from my cloud account in my Python desktop app?**

I chose [Mega](https://mega.nz/) since it offers 20GB of storage for a free account, but I am not sure if this is even a suitable platform for what I'm trying to achieve or is this only for cloud storage, any insights in the right direction to the next move would be really helpful.

*Update:* I tried using mega API, but I'm facing errors logging in

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are there any alternatives or does anyone know how to get rid of this error `mega.errors.RequestError: EACCESS, Access violation` faced during logging in.

The code I used for logging in:

```
    from mega import Mega
    mega = Mega()
    m = mega.login(email, password)
    m = mega.login()
```

Comment: Have you given https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/ a look? This is a python wrapper for the mega API.

Comment: @SamBob Will look into it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SamBob mega API doesn't seem to work, facing errors logging in, updating the question with the error screenshots.

Comment: It looks as though you havent succesfully logged in. But its impossible to tell what is happening without some of your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In addition any code and output should be typed in to your answer, instead of images being posted. This helps users reproduce what you are doing and copy to search without needing to transcribe.

Comment: @SamBob The same from the documentation, have also updated it in the code, seems like a lot of people have been facing this issue logging in as of the issues opened on github of Mega, yet there isn't any proper solution so far.

Comment: I don't know about the Mega API, but in general, you would download the audio file in one thread, write the bytes into a buffer, while playing from this buffer in another thread. When starting playback, you might want to get a listing of available songs first, including their download URLs.

Comment: @Green Does the mean downloading the audio locally into the system, because I don't want to download files into client's system, just like how spotify or any other music apps does, to stream audio without downloading the actual files..

Comment: You definitely have to get the data first, thus, you have to download the files. However, you don't have to write the files onto disk, you can also just put the bytes into a byte buffer into memory (e.g., [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)) and play from there.

Comment: Will look into it, Thanks a lot @Green

Answer (score 2):

I have had success in obtaining files from mega using the `mega.py` package. Install with

```
pip install mega.py
```

And then obtain files to play with:

```
from mega import Mega
import tempfile

# Login to mega
mega = Mega()
email="XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX"
password="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
m = mega.login(email, password)

# Get the file descriptor of a previously uploaded file
filename='file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'
filedesc = m.find(filename)

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    # Download the file to a temporary directory
    downloaded_file_name = m.download(filedesc, tmpdir)
    # replace the following with pygame code for playing the downloaded_file_name file
    print(downloaded_file_name)
```

Where email, password, and filename are replaced as appropriate.

Note that if my email/password are not correct I get a `RequestError` as in the question.

```
mega.errors.RequestError: ENOENT, Object (typically, node or user) not found
```

Once the file is downloaded it can be played in `pygame` as in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-playing-audio-file-in-pygame/

Comment: Thanks a lot @SamBob Logging in worked!

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to stream audio data is to first download the data, write the binary audio data into a virtual file (into memory) and then play audio from this file. The following example demonstrates how to play a wave file from a remote location:

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests
import simpleaudio

response = requests.get("https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav")

audio_stream = BytesIO()
audio_stream.write(response.content)
audio_stream.seek(0)

wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file(audio_stream)
wave_obj.sample_rate = 44000  # TODO: set this appropriately
play_obj = wave_obj.play()  # start playing audio from bytes IO
play_obj.wait_done()
```

This example first downloads the file and then plays it. In order to properly stream the audio, you might to introduce asynchronous processing, e.g., based on threads or async programming, where one thread will fill the byte buffer and another plays from the buffer.

Comment: Facing error installing simpleaudio '  ERROR: Failed building wheel for simpleaudio ' Is there any alternative to it..?

Comment: Yes, there are certainly some. As you implemented your previous player with pygame, you may try to use that instead: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load.